# how to get status if it's success or not by deleting rows in model

Tags: database, codeigniter

i'm still really new to CodeIgniter. and i'm trying to find out how to delete row from my table. because when i use this function, i can;t delete my row.
does anyone know about the solution for this? and how can i get status if the delete is success or not?

```
    public function deleteEpass($serial)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this -> db -> where('serial', $serial);
        $this -> db -> delete('epass');
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return $this->db->trans_status();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

affected_rows( ) should return the number of rows affected. so you can use this.

```html
   $this -> db -> where('serial', $serial);
        $this -> db -> delete('epass');
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->where('serial', $serial);
$this->db->delete('epass');
if (($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)) {
$this->db->trans_rollback();
return FALSE;
} else {
$this->db->trans_commit();
return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```